# Lock out options or answers on Cognito Forms after certain number of entries

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way, using Cognito Forms, to have options "fill up" or become unavailable for selection after a certain number of entries? Similar to a Sign Up Genius type of option.

Answer (score 1):

We are planning to add support for this in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), but want to do this the right way.  Please look at this feature on our Idea Board and upvote and add a comment about how you would use it on your specific form.

https://trello.com/c/wCL0grb2